# Tricky problem on 2× 2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be the $2 \times  2$ matrix $\left[\begin{matrix}
        \sin{\pi/18}  & -\sin{4\pi/9} \\
        \sin{4\pi/9} & \sin{\pi/18} \\
        \end{matrix}
\right]$

Then the smallest number $n \in\mathbb N$ such that $A^n = I$ is

A. 3
B. 9
C. 18
D. 27.

Firstly, I converted the matrix in echelon form to use the fact that $A^n$= power of diagonal element and then equate it to $I$.
I ended up with this: $[\sin{\pi/18}]^n=1$.
Now here i used,$[\sin{\pi/18}]^n = \sin[n{\pi/18}]$.
Will it be correct if i do so?

Comment: I have found that the answer is B

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes the answer is B. But is my method correct?

Comment: Parul, your method is not ok. For one, if $R$ is the echelon form of $A$ there is no reason in general to expect $R^n$ to be the echelon form of $A^n$. This is just as well, for $0<\sin \pi/18<1$, so $(\sin\pi/18)^n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. In other words $(\sin\pi/18)^n\neq\sin n\pi/18$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) of angle $\theta=4\pi/9$, which you may see by first considering that $\frac{4\pi}{9}=\frac{8\pi}{18}$ so $\frac{\pi}{18}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{4\pi}{9}$, then $\sin (\pi/2-x)=\cos (x)$.

Now, the matrix $A^n$ is just the composition of $n$ rotations of angle $4\pi/9$, hence it represents a rotation of angle $4n\pi/9$. For which value of $n$ is this the identity? (answer: for angle a multiple of $2\pi$, so...)

---

Beware: I made a mistake before editing, a rotation matrix **of angle $\theta$** has the form

$$\left(\begin{matrix}\cos \theta & -\sin\theta\\\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{matrix}\right)$$

And **not**

$$\left(\begin{matrix}\sin \theta & -\cos\theta\\\cos\theta & \sin\theta\end{matrix}\right)$$

The latter is also a rotation matrix, of course, but of angle $\pi/2-\theta$, and here it makes a big difference for the answer.

---

If you are using the eigendecomposition of the matrix $A$, then you just have to compute eigenvalues, as eigenvectors will not be needed. For a $2\times2$ matrix, the characteristic polynomial is $x^2-\mathrm{tr}(A) x+\det(A)$, or here $x^2-2\cos\theta+1$, with $\theta=4\pi/9$, hence the discriminant is $4^cos^2\theta-1=-\sin^2\theta$, and the eigenvalues are $\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta=e^{\pm i\theta}$, and from this it's easy to conclude, since the eigenvalues of $A^n$ are then $e^{\pm in\theta}$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $a:=\frac{\pi}{18}$; thus $9a=\frac{\pi}{2}$ from which $8a=\frac{\pi}{2}-a$.

Thus your matrix can be written :

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
        \sin{a}  & -\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-a)\\
        \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-a) & \sin{a} \\
        \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
        \sin{a}  & -\cos{a} \\
        \cos{a} & \sin{a} \\
        \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
        \cos{b}  & -\sin{b} \\
        \sin{b} & \cos{b} \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

with $b:=\frac{\pi}{2}-a=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{18}=4\frac{\pi}{9}.$

which is the classical form of the matrix of rotation with angle $b$.

As $3b$ is not a multiple of $2 \pi$ but $9b=4\pi$ is a multiple of $2\pi$, the answer is $n=9$.

Comment: yes, the answer is 9.

Comment: Yes, stupid computational error. it's now corrected.